# Changing colors when jpg image is opened

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I first saved this image to my local machine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS6CB.jpg

Then I tried to open and show it with this code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('gipsy1.jpg')
img.show()
```

The image displayed by show (or saved into a new file) is slightly different than then original file, as it is possible to check here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmtWG.jpg. Is there any way to avoid this?

Some information about my environment:

- Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) \n[GCC 4.2.1
  Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
- Pillow 4.1.1
- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the lossy compression that the jpg file format uses. What happens if you use a lossless format instead, such as png?

Comment: If you save it to a new file, then it will be re-compressed and the saved file will be different to the original file. There is no way around this. I don't understand what you mean about it being different when it is displayed by `img.show()`, however. What are you comparing it to?

Comment: @SiHa, they're visually different. Colors in the original file are more vivid. Looks like some changes in contrast. It is not a big difference, but final user is complaining about it.

Comment: @Kevin, Just tested it here. Same problem and the same image converted to png is almost 4x larger. =/

Comment: The two screenshots look about the same to me. Could it be that the final user's monitor is poorly calibrated? Two monitors may display the same color completely differently.

Comment: @Kevin, I can see the same differences in my monitor. the sand and clothes are slightly more vivid in original image than the saved one. Thanks for your help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record: this image uses ICC Display P3 space, which is only supported on new Apple products and some other high end displays. If we force ICC to sRGB, we get much better results.

The following code works fine:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('gipsy1.jpg')
import tempfile
from PIL import ImageCms
icc = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.icc')[1]
with open(icc, 'w') as f:
f.write(img.info.get('icc_profile'))
srgb = ImageCms.createProfile('sRGB')
img = ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, icc, srgb)
img.save('new_srgb_gipsy1.jpg')
```